# UIActivityIndicator from no UIView class

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a class  just to pull data from a URL. This is not a UIview class. I want to show a Activity Indicator while downloading the data.

So, how can I add it to the app view? Of course [self.view addSubview... is not the way...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the job of your model object to display any UI. It is the job of the controller is to mediate between the data and the views of your application.

For example, your controller may have a method that starts up your data class and fetches some data. Here it would also display an activity indicator. When your class finishes handing the data back, the controller will remove the spinner from the screen. This keeps the components of your app, reusable. Especially model objects.

Comment: You are right!!! But, how to save time and code? I have to insert the same code in a lot of places in my app!

Comment: humm... I have tabBarController, and several UIViewControllers on it. The best place to put this code is in the rootViewController?

Comment: I'm saying the best place to put a spinner on screen is when you use the data object in one of your view controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the window property from your app delegate

```
[[(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedAplication] delegate] window] addSubview:yourActivityIndicator];
```

Dont forget to:

```
#import "YourAppDelegate.h"
```

Comment: But What Mark Adams says, its completely true! but you know... patterns == philosophies == ways to see the world